# Xubuntu, combinations Ctrl+key don't work when I use Ctrl as hotkey for switching keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, xfce

On Xubuntu 18.04 I'm using hotkey right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> for switching keyboard layout. And now I can't use any combinations with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ in applications.

And for example if I use <kbd>Alt</kbd> for switching layout, combinations <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> also doesn't work.

How to fix this?

Update. Solutions for Ubuntu Gnome and Ubuntu Mate don't work here. I can't add second hotkey for switching layout in Xubuntu/xfce.

Comment: Did it work in previous versions?

Comment: It's my first Xubuntu. Before used 16.04 Unity. Everything was fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a solution I installed **xcape** - https://github.com/alols/xcape

Follow instruction from `README.md` how to install it on your system.

Then run

```
xcape -e 'Control_R=Alt_L|Shift_L'
```

and add the command to the autorun.

Pay attention that your command may be different if you don't use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> as default shortcut for switching keyboard layout.